# ddrescue stuck, Error Splicing DVD file on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dvd, ddrescue, scratch

I have couple of old scratched DVDs which I wanted to rescue using ddrescue.
The problem is it shows "error splicing file" on copying files manually using PartedMagic or Ubuntu, also ddrescue gets stuck at 0.14% and can't rescue the rest of the DVD, but when I start the laptop to Windows, it will copy all files of the DVD without any errors.
I trust ddrescue more than any Windows tool for the scratched DVD backup job. So I need a solution to get ddrescue to copy contents of DVDs successfully.

Comment: Have you checked if the Windows-made copy is correct?

Comment: @harrymc yes, the copied files are correct and even files on dvd are playable in windows !!!

Answer (score 1):

As you tested the files copied under Windows and they come up as correct,
I suggest respectfully that there is no need to run `ddrescue`.

Different operating systems access the devices differently, with different
drivers, so one may fail where the other one succeeds.

Comment: Well the problem is that I have bunch of scratched dvds, which windows manual copy or windows tools can't copy them correctly. And I want to use ddrescue to rescue the files on them, So I need a way to make it work in linux OS

Comment: It works as well as it can. You should look for other utilities if that's not good enough.

Comment: well the best utility that I have come across is ddrescue. Root of the problem is in linux os, not the tool itself. 'Cause the error persist using any tool in linux

Comment: Yes, your problem is mostly the disc driver. ddrescue issues the read request specifying not to wait in case of error. Apparently this part is ignored here. If the problem occurs at the beginning,  `--R` will start from the end. You should be able to stop ddrescue as it uses the log file to be able to restart its operation (close) to where it left of, but you should verify first that it really wrote something to the log. Sometimes using another reader helps, maybe on another computer, copying the log file each time.

Comment: I tried it with 3 different PCs & dvd roms, but I haven't used --R flag yet. Will try that & report the results. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: well I tested ddrescue again with -R flag & the problem still persists. I'm so disappointed at the way linux handles scrached dvds ...

Comment: I was afraid of that. ddrescue needs to complete the first scan before writing anything to the log. Sorry, I can't change Linux. Maybe this is why there are better rescue tools to be found on Windows.

Comment: yeah, I ended up using IsoBuster to take an image of the scratched ones

Comment: If this answer gave you the right explanation, you might think to accept it.

Comment: i had the same. i was opening the dvd through /media/<myusername> this gave splicing errors while copying at some dvd, some not, so i was unable to copy anything really of this dvd. then i ripped the same dvd with vlc through /dev/sr0 and it seems to be working. (suppose different drivers)